# How to remove new Function with Anonymous function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, anonymous-function

I am trying to replace eval/new Function with corresponding anonymous function.

**Existing Code -**

```
var y = 2
var fn = new Function("return" +y)
console.log(fn)
```

When i print **fn** output is

```
ƒ anonymous(
) {
return2
}
```

**Refactored code which i am writing -**

```
var y = 2
var fn1 = function()  {return y}
console.log(fn1)
```

But fn1 in this case is

```
ƒ ()  {return y}
```

Any pointers how can i get the same output as fn `ƒ anonymous() {return2}` using my own anonymous function.

Comment: The way `console` outputs variables is not bound to a strict output format. So this can look different from one `console` implementation to another.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

You can't (at least not without using another version of `eval`).

You can get the same *effect* (i.e. not having a mutable `y`) by using a closure.

```js
var y = 2
var fn1 = function(closure_y) {
  return function() {
    return closure_y;
  }
}(y)
y = 3;
console.log(fn1())
```

If your code depends on a function stringifying itself in a particular way, then you should probably rewrite the code so it no longer depends on that.